# Firebase Messaging Not working on IOS when app running in background or closed

Tags: swift, firebase, flutter, dart

The app is sending push Notification but when app running in background or close. i will not receive any notification...

i am receiving Notification successful when using Phone Auth.

**Following steps are done.**

> Generated app ID and push Key in

**https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/**

> Added info.plist to ios/Runner folder
>
> Turned on Push capabilities
>
> Uploaded APNS certificate to Firebase console

**i am using the Latest Version of Firebase Messaging**

**here is my code**

```
class _MyProfileState extends State<MyProfile> {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.max,
  );

  Future<void> saveTokenToDatabase(String token) async {
    String userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
    await firestore.collection("users").doc(userId).update({
      'tokens': token,
    });
  }

  Map dataset;
  bool state = false;
  String selected = "first";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    getTokens();
    getUserLocation();
  }

  getTokens() async {
    String token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    await saveTokenToDatabase(token);
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen(saveTokenToDatabase);
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');
      if (message.notification != null) {
        print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
      }
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;

      // If `onMessage` is triggered with a notification, construct our own
      // local notification to show to users using the created channel.

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: android?.smallIcon,
                // other properties...
              ),
            ));
      }
    });
  }

  getData() async {
    setState(() {
      state = true;
    });
    final datastore =
        await firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        setState(() {
          dataset = datastore.data();
          state = false;
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

here is my Cloud Function that trigger the Notification

```
exports.likeFunction = functions.firestore.document("Likes/{UserLikeId}/userLikes/{meId}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
        console.log('No Device');
    }
    //1. get the user that like id
    const meId = context.params.meId;
    //2. get the id the of the person u are liking
    const UserLikeId = context.params.UserLikeId;
    //3. we get all the document of user that like
    const me = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(meId).get();
    //4. we get all the document of the person we are liking 
    const deviceToken = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(UserLikeId).get();
    //5. the user that like name
    const name = me.data()['name'];
    console.log(deviceToken.id);
    //6. push notification to the person we are liking
    try {
        await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
            deviceToken.data()['tokens'],
            {
                notification: {
                    title: 'likes',
                    body: `${name} Likes You`,
                    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
                },
            },
            {
                contentAvailable: true,
                priority: "high",
            }
        );
        console.log("Firebase Like Messaging Successfully");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error from Like messaging " + err);
    }
    //7. we add to the activities of the person we are liking
    admin.firestore().collection('feeds').doc(UserLikeId).collection('feedsItems').doc().set({
        'type': 'Like',
        'name': me.data()['name'],
        'photo': me.data()['profilePictureUrl'],
        'seen': false,
        'content': `${me.data()['name']} Like You...`,
        'timestamp': Date.now()
    });
})
```

All this is working fine on Android

Comment: is it working from the cloud messaging console directly if you send it?

Comment: yes... is showing the sucessfull message

Comment: do you get the notification on ios but from the console

Comment: i dont get notification on ios and console

Comment: but in the cloud messaging console  the status is ok

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbQrVNJpHkU check this if you followed all the steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235703/discussion-between-himeshp-and-gbenga-b-ayannuga).

Comment: this is old implementation...

Comment: i have all in that video, but no swift code in the AppDelegate